# Using aws embedded metrics with FastAPI (EMF CloudWatch)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to use aws_embedded_metrics with FastAPI.

It requires you to use the custom decorator `@metric_scope` to your app:

```
from aws_embedded_metrics import metric_scope, MetricsLogger

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
@metric_scope
def test(metrics: MetricsLogger):
  metrics.set_namespace("blah")
  metrics.put_dimensions({"EnvironmentName": env})

  return {"status": {"httpStatusCode": 200}, "data": []}
```

Here's the source code of the `@metric_scope`:

```
from aws_embedded_metrics.logger.metrics_logger_factory import create_metrics_logger
import inspect
import asyncio
from functools import wraps


def metric_scope(fn):  # type: ignore

    if asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(fn):

        @wraps(fn)
        async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):  # type: ignore
            logger = create_metrics_logger()
            if "metrics" in inspect.signature(fn).parameters:
                kwargs["metrics"] = logger
            try:
                return await fn(*args, **kwargs)
            except Exception as e:
                raise e
            finally:
                await logger.flush()

        return wrapper
    else:

        @wraps(fn)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):  # type: ignore
            logger = create_metrics_logger()
            if "metrics" in inspect.signature(fn).parameters:
                kwargs["metrics"] = logger
            try:
                return fn(*args, **kwargs)
            except Exception as e:
                raise e
            finally:
                loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
                loop.run_until_complete(logger.flush())

        return wrapper
```

However, this fails with the following exception:
`fastapi.exceptions.FastAPIError: Invalid args for response field! Hint: check that <class 'aws_embedded_metrics.logger.metrics_logger.MetricsLogger'> is a valid Pydantic field type. If you are using a return type annotation that is not a valid Pydantic field (e.g. Union[Response, dict, None]) you can disable generating the response model from the type annotation with the path operation decorator parameter response_model=None. Read more: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/`

How can I fix this?

I'm using both `def` and `async def` in my app for the routes, the above is just an example.

Comment: "fixing" that with `Depends[]` fails with `RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'AnyIO worker thread'.` due to `metrics.flush()` method being async. Anyone knows a fix?